# Else statement if condition in for loop doesn't go off

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am writing a simple for loop in Javascript. It works, but now I want to add an option to it that fires if the condition in the for loop isn't met. If I put an else condition in the for loop it gets triggered 'i' times. How do I make it fire ones? 'break' won't do the trick since it will stop the for loop completely. How do I make the for loop check 'i' times if the condition if met, and if it isn't met 'i' times, do something. Thanks

```
onClickContact : function(component, event, helper){
  var accountInfo     = component.get('v.accountInfo');
  var mailTo          = component.get('v.mailTo');

  for ( var i = 0; i < mailTo.length; i++) {
   if ( mailTo[i].Country__c == Account.BillingCountry){
      window.location.href = mailTo[i].Mailto__c;
   } 
  }
 }
```

Comment: Write a break statement in the else condition, it'll come out of the loop when your condition meets.

Comment: put an else statement with break.

Comment: few `break;`s are your friend, many of them your nemesis...

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Should the `for` loop keep running and the `else` should only be executed once or should the `for` loop quit as soon as the `else` condition is executed?

Comment: Just `return` when you have a match. After the `for` loop ends you can treat the other condition.

Comment: the for loop should keep running and the else should be executed once. So when the condition isn;t met 'i' times: do something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
onClickContact : function(component, event, helper){
  var accountInfo     = component.get('v.accountInfo');
  var mailTo          = component.get('v.mailTo');

  for ( var i = 0, var k = false; i < mailTo.length; i++) {
   if ( mailTo[i].Country__c == Account.BillingCountry){
      window.location.href = mailTo[i].Mailto__c;
      k = true;
   }
   if(i == mailTo.length-1 && !k) {
     /* your code if the condition isn't met at all.*/
   }
 }
```

Comment: This stops the for loop when the condition isn't met once. I want the for loop to keep running and if it isn't met 'i' times, than do something else

Comment: what do you mean 'i' times. As I see, 'i' is a variable. Are you saying that for some other constant say 'j' , if the loop doesn't meet 'j' times, you should print something? That you can with a counter 'j' along with 'i' in loop.

Comment: @Ant look at the code.

Comment: if mailto.length is 14, I want to check all the 14 mailto's if the meet the condition. If all the 14 don't meet the condition, than I want to execute some other code

Comment: so if the condition is met at least once, you don't want to execute the code?

Comment: No, If the condition is met once I want to execute the code in the for loop. If the condition is not met at all, I want to execute some other code. Would you know how to write that?

Comment: try the edit, please